# difference in how mv command acts in dockerfile and on my local linux

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, wildfly

I am looking at the following jboss/wildfly [docker file](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/dockerfile) which has the following command:

```
mv $HOME/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION $JBOSS_HOME
```

where `$WILDFLY_VERSION=17.0.1.Final` and `$JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/wildfly.`Thus the resulting command translates to:

```
mv $HOME/wildfly-17.0.1.Final /opt/jboss/wildfly
```

Later in the file we start the wildfly like this:

```
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

So I assume that the `mv` command from the above took the content of  `$HOME/wildfly-17.0.1.Final` directory and put it inside the `/opt/jboss/wildfly` directory.

However, if I try to recreate the steps from the dockerfile on my local machine (ubuntu 18.04) when I do `mv $HOME/wildfly-17.0.1.Final /opt/jboss/wildfly`, I end up with the following directory structure `/opt/jboss/wildfly/wildfly-17.0.1.Final`. That is, the `wildfly-17.0.1.Final` directory itself is copied into `/opt/jboss/wildfly`, rather than its content.
Can somebody please explain why I get this result locally?

Comment: Are you sure you tried this `mv $HOME/wildfly-17.0.1.Final /opt/jboss/wildfly` and not this `mv $HOME/wildfly-17.0.1.Final /opt/jboss/wildfly/` The `/` at the end of wildfly

Comment: I tried both and in both cases I got the same result.

Comment: The docker file has the following definition ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/jboss/wildfly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$JBOSS_HOME` path doesn't exist.

What the `mv` command does is actually replace the non-existent directory with the `$HOME/wildfly-17.0.1.Final` folder. That been said, the content of `$HOME/wildfly-17.0.1.Final/` will be moved into `$JBOSS_HOME` replacing the name of the folder from "wildfly-17.0.1.Final" into "wildfly".

Simple Example would be as follow:

Create an empty dir and touch a file inside it, then try to do:

```
mv dir /var/lib/non_existing_folder
```

dir will be moved as is and replace "non_existing_folder".

Comment: This is the correct answer, I tried it locally and it worked.